# jQuery loop image fadeout/in with time interval

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have a jQuery function to fadeIn/Out images in a div. But when the function reaches last image, it gets stopped. Any way to get it in a loop, so that at the end of last image, it will start again from the first image.
here is the code

HTML:

```
<div id="homeimg">
    <img src="image1.jpg" />
    <img src="image2.jpg" />
    <img src="image3.jpg" />
    <img src="image4.jpg" />
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#homeimg img:first-child').addClass('activeimg');
   setInterval('cycleMe()', 4000);
});

function cycleMe() {
  $('.activeimg').next().css('z-index', 10);
  $('.activeimg').next().fadeIn(1500);
  $('.activeimg').fadeOut(1500, function(){
      $(this).next().fadeIn(0);
      $(this).next().addClass('activeimg');
      $(this).css('z-index', 5).removeClass('activeimg');
  });
 }
```

Any possibilities?

Comment: Don't pass the function in as a string, it's inefficient.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it. I'm a beginner in js. Didn't understand why it's inefficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also do this with simple array manipulation:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('#homeimg img:first-child').addClass('activeimg');
   setInterval(cycleMe, 4000);
   // get an array of your images
   var arrImgs = $('#homeimg img');

   function cycleMe() {
       var currImg = arrImgs[0];
       var nextImg = arrImgs[1];
       // You can do this with simple array splicing and pushing
       $(nextImg).css('z-index', 10);
       $(nextImg).fadeIn(1500);
       $(currImg).fadeOut(1500, function () {
           $(nextImg).fadeIn(0);
           $(this).css('z-index', 5);
           // remove the first item from the array
           arrImgs.splice(0,1);
           // add it to the end of the array
           arrImgs.push(currImg);
       });
   }
});
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mori57/4FbVD/

Taking into consideration some of Ethan's comments, I also tried it this way:

http://jsfiddle.net/mori57/4FbVD/2/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#homeimg img:first-child').addClass('activeimg');
    setInterval(cycleMe, 4000);
    // get an array of your images
    var arrImgs = $('#homeimg img');

    function cycleMe() {
        var currImg = $(arrImgs[0]);
        var nextImg = $(arrImgs[1]);
        // You can do this with simple array splicing and pushing
        nextImg.fadeIn(1500);
        currImg.fadeOut(1500, function () {
            currImg.removeClass('activeimg');
            nextImg.fadeIn(0).addClass('activeimg');
            // remove the first item from the array
            arrImgs.splice(0,1);
            // add it to the end of the array
            arrImgs.push(currImg);
        });
    }
});
```

In my previous attempt, I was having to requery the DOM both for css change and fadeIn ... inefficient. Cache the jQuery object, /then/ do the manipulation, and sans-z-index as in Ethan's approach. I'd still rather not have to requery the DOM at all for each element inside an infinite loop. If I find a way around that, I'll post it as well.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you're passing the function in as a string, which is a no-no.  I think you're over-complicating your code, and there are some jQuery efficiencies you can leverage.

First, I don't think it's necessary to modify the z-index of your images: the fading should handle all that.  Secondly, you can chain jQuery calls (see below how `fadeIn` and `addClass` chained).  Lastly, every time you do `$('.activeimage')`, jQuery has to scan the DOM again, which is inefficient.  Best to do it once and cache the answer (whenever I store a jQuery object, I begin it with a dollar sign by convention, so I always know I'm dealing with a jQuery-wrapped object).

Here's how I would re-write this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#homeimg img:first-child').addClass('activeimg');
    setInterval(cycleMe, 4000);
});

function cycleMe() {
    var $active = $('#homeimg .activeimg');
    var $next = $active.next('img');
    if(!$next.length) $next = $('#homeimg img:first-child');

    $active.fadeOut(1500, function(){
        $(this).removeClass('activeimg');
        $next.fadeIn().addClass('activeimg');
    });
 }
```

Working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6MHDn/

Comment: OP stated they wanted a loop, so it would repeat infinitely.

Comment: Ah, you're right.  I should have read more carefully!  Will correct in a minute.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I put your code here- http://jsfiddle.net/sreejeshts/3HnNc/  It makes a loop, however after showing the last image, it gets some time to start it again.

Comment: @Ethan Brown A code from **@mori57** worked. Though it is different way, it will definitely help me. Thanks for your time answering my question.

Comment: I didn't read your question carefully enough.  I'm going to update my answer now.  Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. It's the same effect I mean. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Same effect, true.  I feel like my code is a little more compact/maintainable than mori57's, but some days, it's all about the first thing that works!  Some days you just want to get it working and go home :)

Comment: The only issue I'd take with @EthanBrown's approach, and my first stab at it, is having to select the elements in each call. Ideally, I'd hoped that the array returned outside of the loop would get jQuery objects for each item in the array, but I found on testing that I had to reselect each one every time through. Still, Ethan's approach is solid and preserves your `.activeimg` class, too.

Comment: Good point, mori.  It would be pretty easy to move the object cache outside of the function.

Comment: An even better approach would be writing a custom jQuery plugin, so you could just do `$('#homeimg').slideshow()` :)